# Shell no such file or directory

Tags: linux, shell

While trying to run a for loop in shell I encountered a problem.

```
for i in `cat $file`
do
`cut -d ',' -f 2- $i`
done
```

I tried to cut the lines from the second column and output them, however it gave me an error: (content of the file) no such file or directory

Comment: That's not the way `cut` works. You want for `cut -d ',' -f 2- "$file"`. No loop is required.

Comment: This means that the variable `i` contains a file which does not exist. Another possibility is that `i` contains a valid file name, but it has a space in it. You can verify both possibilities by turning on `set -x` before entering the loop.

Comment: It looks like you need a basic shell tutorial.  What do you think the backticks do, and why are you using them at all?  Your problem is easily solved with `awk '{print $2}' "$file"`

Comment: Also, [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: @WilliamPursell your awk doesn't use comma for FS and doesn't print $3 onward

Answer (score 1):

First, you try to execute the output of the `cut` command.

Consider:

```
$ echo hello >file
$ cat file
hello
$ a=`cat file`
$ echo "$a"
hello
$ `echo "$a"`
-bash: hello: not found
$
```

Perhaps you just wanted to display the output of `cut`:

```
for i in `cat "$file"`
do
    cut -d , -f 2- $i
done
```

Second, you pass `cut` an argument that is expected to be a filename.

You read data from `$file` and use it as a filename. Is that data actually a filename?

Consider:

```
$ echo a,b,c,d >file
$ cat file
a,b,c,d
$ a=`cat file`
$ echo "$a"
a,b,c,d
$ cut -d , -f 2- file
b,c,d
$ cut -d , -f 2- "$a"
cut: a,b,c,d: No such file or directory
```

Perhaps you wanted:

```
cut -d , -f 2- "$file"
```

Thirdly, your `for` loop splits the data in `"$file"` on whitespace, not by line.

Consider:

```
$ echo 'a   b,c d' >file
$ cat file
a   b,c d
$ for i in `cat file`; do echo "[$i]"; done
[a]
[b,c]
[d]
$
```

Perhaps you wanted to read individual lines?

```
while read i; do
    : ...
done <file
```